# Uncaught TypeError: filteredProducts.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting an error that this is not a function , I tried to figure out what the problem is and in my opinion I found that while I am getting the data using useState it is not saving in products, whereas while I am doing

```
setProducts(res.data)
       console.log(res);
```

it is giving me my data as a response
as an object
,the (cat,filters,sort) i am getting as a prop from ProductList

the code for which looks like this

```
const location = useLocation();
    const cat = (location.pathname.split("/")[2]);

    const [filters,setFilters] = useState({})
    const [sort,setSorts] = useState("newest")

    const handleFilters = (e)=>{
        const value = e.target.value;
        setFilters({
            ...filters,
            [e.target.name] :value,
        })
    }
```

```
const Products = ({ cat, filters, sort }) => {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState({})
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredroducts] = useState({})


  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(cat ? `http://localhost:5000/api/products?category=${cat}` : "http://localhost:5000/api/products");
        setProducts(res.data)
        console.log(res);
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getProducts();
  }, [cat])

  console.log(products);
```

this is the code where I am storing data in products using useState
but later I found that it is not even stored in products
the further code is as folllows but i don't think so it will work

```
  useEffect(() => {
    cat && setFilteredroducts(
      products.filter((item) => Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) =>
        item[key].includes(value)
      ))
    )
  }, [products, cat, filters]);
```

and this is the container where i am mapping it

```
return (
    <Container>
      {filteredProducts.map(item => (
        <Product item={item} key={item.id} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  )
```

Comment: **It's just a typo-level error, folks.** @​ShubhamJain - `{}` is a plain object, not an array. Plain objects don't have a `map` method. `[]` is a blank array. So use `useState([])` instead of `useState({})` (probably for both `products` and `filteredProducts`).

Comment: You probably want to fix `setFilteredroducts` while you are at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is with initial value of the state

try to change

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState({})
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredroducts] = useState({})
```

with

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredroducts] = useState([])
```

`filteredProducts` at the beginning is an empty object `{}` and `Object` doesn't have a `map` method